# Kendo Mvc DropdownList, How to set Initial Value

Tags: c#, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i am using Kendo DropdownList with ajax binding.

With these codes i cannot set inital value that coming from model.It just fill the list with items and selects the first item.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
 .Name("NATIONALITY") 
 .DataTextField("DESCRIPTION").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:220px" }) 
 .DataValueField("REFERENCEID")
 .Value(Model.NATIONALITY)
         //Placeholder("SELECT")
  .DataSource(source =>
                        {
  source.Read(read =>
             {
        read.Action("GetDefinitionDetails", "Definition", new { definitionCode = "NATIONALITY", addEmptyRow = false });
                            }).ServerFiltering(true);
                            }).ServerFiltering(true);
                        }))
```

But When i change Html.Kendo().DropDownList() to Html.Kendo().Combobox() it also fills the list and set the initial value as expected(which is the value that passing by model.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the latest(maybe works on earlier versions) build of KendoUI , initial Text value can be set on dropdowns:

```
   ....
   .Value(Model.DOCTORCODE.ToString()) //DOCTORCODE is  guid type
   .Text(Model.DOCTOR)  //DOCTOR is string type.This is optional.It should work without .Text property
```

Answer (score 7):

On the `Kendo DropDownList` you can specify the `SelectedIndex` as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().SelectedIndex(myIndex)
 .//other builder stuff
```

With the `DropDownList` you can only specify the index of the item that is to be selected. You cannot chose this item by its text.

Using the client-side API you can set set selected value based on the text, by using [the value method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-value). Just add an e[vent on the data bound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DropDownListEventBuilder#methods-DataBound%28System.String%29) that calls a JavaScript function. This function can then select the desired item based on its text.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I can add databound event but dont know how to retrieve Model property's(which is NATIONALITY )value on javascript

Comment: Since you're using Razor syntax, to access "C# objects" in JavaScript you need to add an `@` before the variable name: `function test(){alert(@Model.NATIONALITY );}`.

Comment: i tried but @model.Nationality seems null because it initialized before read action runs.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was naming the dropdownlist box the same as the property in the model:

```
View model (adminUserViewModel.cs)

//....other properties....
[Display(Name = "Security Level")]
[UIHint("SecurityLevelsEditor")]
public SecurityLevelViewModel securityLevel { get; set; }

in my /Views/Shared folder I have a custom template named:

 SecurityLevelsEditor.cshtml 

@model WebAdmin.Models.SecurityLevelViewModel
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("securityLevel")
.DataTextField("levelDescription")
.DataValueField("securityLevelID")
.DataSource(datasource => datasource.Read(source => source.Action("Index", "SecurityLevels"))
)
```

)

Here's how it's wired up in the index.cshtml file:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAdmin.Models.AdminUserViewModel>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("adminUsersGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>{
    columns.Bound(item => item.userName);
    columns.Bound(item => item.securityLevel).ClientTemplate("#: securityLevel.levelDescription #" );    
    columns.Bound(item => item.firstName);
    columns.Bound(item => item.lastName);
    columns.Bound(item => item.email);
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
})
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m => {
            m.Id(p => p.userID);
            m.Field(item => item.securityLevel).DefaultValue(ViewData["defaultSecurityLevel"] as WebAdmin.Models.SecurityLevelViewModel);
        })
        .Update(u => u.Action("Update", "UserAdmin"))
        .Create(c => c.Action("_Create", "UserAdmin"))
        .Destroy(x => x.Action("_Destroy", "UserAdmin"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("clientIndex", "UserAdmin", new { id = @ViewBag.accountID }))
     )
    .Pageable().Sortable().Filterable()
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("AdminUserPopup"))

)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdownlist is in a template, use `.HtmlAttributes` to set initial value.

```
@(Html.Kendo()
    .DropDownList()
    .Name("barDropdown")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .DataSource(ds => ds
        .Read(read => read.Action("getBar", "SomeController").Type(HttpVerbs.Post)))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { value = "#:BarValue#" })
    .ToClientTemplate()
    )
```